# A question about topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Assume $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space,

$f:X\rightarrow X$,
 if $x\neq y$，then $d(f(x),f(y))＜d(x,y)$

prove that there exists $x$，such that $f(x)＝x$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is a special case of what is known as the Banach fixed point theorem or the contraction mapping theorem (note that for metric spaces compact$\implies$ complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $K_0=X$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $K_{n+1}=f[K_n]$.

- Show that $K_{n+1}\subseteq K_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.
- Show that $\operatorname{diam}K_{n+1}<\operatorname{diam}K_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, where $\operatorname{diam}K=\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in K\}$.

Let $K=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n$

- Show that $K\ne\varnothing$ and that $f[K]=K$.
- Conclude that $K=\{x\}$ for some fixed point $x$ of $f$.